# Inverse of JavaScript Object.assign

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a flat JavaScript object called `dictionary` that I want to update based on other flat objects. Sometimes I want to add every property of an object to `dictionary` and sometimes I want to delete every key in `dictionary` that exists in another object. I'll be using the values of those properties later, but for the sake of managing `dictionary`, I only care about their names.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/171251/5931898) question, I know how to merge properties (using, for instance, `Object.assign`). How can I do the inverse of that? `Object.unassign` doesn't exist, but is there anything similar?

For example:

```
dictionary = { foo: 'bar', baz: 'qux' };
object1 = { spam: 'spam' };

Object.assign(dictionary, object1); // dictionary now has properties: foo, baz, spam

object2 = { foo: 'spam', baz: 'qux' };

Object.unassign(dictionary, object2); // dictionary is now only { spam: 'spam' }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no such built-in function, but it would be quite trivial to write your own that accomplishes something like that:

```js
const dictionary = { foo: 'bar', baz: 'qux' };
const object1 = { spam: 'spam' };
const object2 = { foo: 'spam', baz: 'qux' };

Object.assign(dictionary, object1);

const unassign = (target, source) => {
  Object.keys(source).forEach(key => {
    delete target[key];
  });
};
unassign(dictionary, object2);
console.log(dictionary);
```

(Although you *could* change `Object.prototype` and add this `unassign` function to it, mutating the built-in objects is *very* bad practice - better to make a standalone function)

Answer (score 1):

Another beautiful way I found is via object destructuring…

```js
const dictionary = { foo: 'bar', baz: 'qux', spam: 'spam' };
const {foo, baz, ...newDictionary} = dictionary;
console.log(newDictionary) // { spam: 'spam' }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `unassign` function in the accepted answer is missing 3 facets that are present in `Object.assign`:

1. `Object.assign` accepts 1 `target` argument and N `source` arguments, but `unassign` accepts 1 `target` argument and 1 `source` argument.
2. `Object.assign` assigns nested objects of any depth, but `unassign` unassigns objects only at depth = 1.
3. `Object.assign` returns the `target` object, but `unassign` does not return anything.

The following function supports these three missing facets:

```js
function unassign(target, ...sources) {
  for (let source of sources) {
    for (let id in source) {
      const targetValue = target[id];
      if (targetValue) {
        const sourceValue = source[id];
        if (sourceValue !== null && typeof sourceValue === "object" && !Array.isArray(sourceValue) && typeof targetValue === "object" && !Array.isArray(targetValue))
          unassign(targetValue, sourceValue);
        else
          delete target[id];
      }
    }
  }

  return target;
}
```